# Inadvertent paste when correcting spelling mistakes using flyspell

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, copy-paste, mouse, flyspell

When I click with the middle mouse button that usually inserts the primary selection at the point where I clicked.  However, the same button opens flyspell's context menu when I click on a misspelled word.  The problem is that when I use the context menu to, e.g., save a word to the dictionary, this also inserts the primary selection after the flyspell action is finished.  I thought that this problem may be due to a mess-up in my configuration but I can also reproduce this with `emacs -Q`.  How can I fix this?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start `emacs -Q`.
2. Insert the following sentence (in the scratch buffer):

   Here is a sentence with a mistaake.
3. `M-x flyspell-buffer`, the word *mistaake* is highlighted.
4. Double click on *sentence* to select it.
5. Click middle mouse button (mouse-2) on *mistaake*, choose the correct spelling *mistake* from the context memu.

Result: *mistaake* is replaced with *missentecetake*.

I found some really old bug reports that sound related (going back to 2005) but no working solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you are being bitten by the fact that one command is bound to `mouse-2`, another command is bound to `down-mouse-2`, and the two commands do not play well together.

Do `C-h k` and then click `mouse-2` on text (e.g. `mistaake`). The help should tell you what `mouse-2` and `down-mouse-2` are bound to.

If I'm right in my guess, you can try doing one of these things:

- Move your yank command to a different key sequence (but I would keep it as a yank).
- Move the flyspell command to another key sequence.
- Swap the two bindings (for click down and up).  Worth a try, at least.
- Put a renamed copy of the flyspell command on the up action and modify the copy so that it ignores the down event. IOW, make the flyspell command play well with a non-menu command bound to the down event.

Personally, I would count this as a (key-binding) bug in flyspell -- clicking `mouse-2` should usually yank in Emacs, in one form or another. The flyspell developers should be able to make flyspell cohabit with down or up clicks that yank text. (But I imagine that the flyspell people won't see it that way.)

(Disclosure: I am not a flyspell user.  With luck, someone who uses it will provide a simple solution and explanation.)

---

Looking at the flyspell.el code, I see that it does this:

```
(if (featurep 'xemacs)
    (define-key map [button2] #'flyspell-correct-word)
  (define-key map [down-mouse-2] #'flyspell-correct-word)
  (define-key map [mouse-2] 'undefined))
```

Are you using XEmacs?  If not, try changing `undefined` to `ignore`, here. Dunno whether that will make a difference, but it might be worth a try.

Actually, try it the other way around:

```
(if (featurep 'xemacs)
    (define-key map [button2] #'flyspell-correct-word)
  (define-key map [mouse-2] #'flyspell-correct-word) ; REVERSED the bindings
  (define-key map [down-mouse-2] 'ignore))
```

That is usually what I do. For example, in [`isearch+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/isearch%2b.el) I do this:

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map [mouse-2]      'isearch-mouse-2)
(define-key isearch-mode-map [down-mouse-2] 'ignore)
```

Comment: Setting `mouse-2` to `ignore` didn't help but reversing the bindings did.  Thank you very much.  This bug was annoying me for way too long.

Comment: Glad it helped. You might consider contacting the flyspell maintainers (which I guess is Emacs Dev, so `M-x report-emacs-bug`, which is not only for bugs). They might want to change something, or they might have some useful advice for users in this regard.